# Capture dynamically loaded images

Tags: javascript, analytics

Adobe uses document.images to get a list of dynamically generated images. This helps their custom tool provide a visual representation of what we is being tracked.

Since document.images is only for elects specified on the HTML how does Adobe accomplish this capture feature? You can see in Chrome's the Network tab when the images are being loaded.

You can see a sample by looking at Adobe PDP: https://www.adobetag.com/d1/digitalpulsedebugger/live/DPD.js

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find the exact method that Adobe uses, however after the code has loaded there is a variable name assigned which has the URL content with all the parameters. I am able to wait for this element in order to find out exactly what I was looking for.